# What is the best way to use websockets along with PHP and MySQL scripts?

Tags: php, mysql, websocket, ratchet

What is the best way to use websockets along with PHP and MySQL scripts?

If I want to add a live chat to my PHP site, or store vars to the MySQL database when doing X action in real time (for a RPG website trading, for example).

I have found [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/), it's a good choice to achieve those things efficiently? Maybe using Node.js and PHP at the same time? I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: See this article on the state of realtime web tech and PHP http://www.leggetter.co.uk/2013/10/18/the-current-state-of-realtime-web-tech-for-php.html

Comment: What do you think about using jQuery / Javascript for client side to send the websocket, then Node.js as websocket server and, if needed, call PHP scripts / functions through dnode-php. That way I won't have to deal with websockets with PHP directly, but I could still keep my website in PHP and let Node.js to handle websockets communication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same question a few months ago, and answered it for myself after some tinkering and research.

I used Node.js in combination with PHP.

Basically, it works like this.
Apache/php send a page to the client on request. It contains an auth token. 
The browser Initializes socket.io and sends the token back to a node js server. Node then sends the token to a private API (if you will) to the Apache server requesting needed context on the user (user id for example). When node gets this back, it stores it in a `"connection ID" => "user ID"` table. (or routing table (fancy specific term for a hash map))

If a user sends a "chat" message to another user, it goes to Apache via ajax, does the database/processing stuff, then passes it back to Node.js on the back-end which plugs the user id into the routing table and sends the message to the users browser.

I cant post code because this may be used in production at some point but that Is how I did it with a LAMP based server.

NOTES: You will need to have a string account management system implemented for this to work, and I implemented this concept for my own account handling system so it is very application specific in my case.

The need for the token is for security. This token for example could be a sessions ID. Something that can derive the user ID on the back-end, but not on the front end. It should change periodically. This way, if it is compromised, the attacker wont be able to connect to the live session for long, or at all.

This concept can be improved. Such as a per-request token, that changes on every request that may only be used once. This is currently something I am working on with my live notification system.